# Get nested procedure and sql execution oracle

Tags: oracle, query-performance

In my Oracle 11g environment, I got performance issue with a procedure named : myProc().
In myProc() it's called to others proc named myChildProcA(), myChildProcB(),myChildProcC()......( ~10 child procedures)

In Postgresql, I have some userful tool like pg_stat_user_functions, pg_stat_statements, auto_explain...
it's provide detail information about child function excutions.
But I don't known much about Oracle.
I tried with v$sql, sql_trace and tkprof to get statistic information but it's not provide child procedure information.

My question :
Are there any way or tool to get elapsed executions time for child procedures in Oracle?

Answer (score 0):

`v$sql` gives you the information at a SQL child cursor level and sql_trace gives you the information at a SQL execution level. `v$sql` also tells you the `program_id` and the `program_line#` of the compiled pl/sql code that last hard parsed it.

That said, you are probably looking for the [Hierarchical Profiler](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e41502/adfns_profiler.htm)